# laravel file upload using custam library

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

"I'm tring to upload file using custome library in laravel file goes in folder successfully but file isn't upload in database

this is my custom library:-

```
namespace App\Classes;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Hello
{

    static function jai(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasfile('name'))
        {

        $image=$request->file('name');
        $new_image=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('image/'),$new_image);

        }

    }
}
?>

and this is my controller store function :-    
        Hello::jai($request);
        $x=$request->all();
        $x['name']=
        $j=Hello::jai($request)->new_image;
        Cruds::create($x);
```

The file "[000004].jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
    public function upload(Request $request){
    if($file = $request->file('file')){
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        if($file->move('files',$name)){
            $file= new Files();//DB instance modal
            $file->url= $name;
            $file->save();
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the file extension. See if this help you.

```
$image = $request->file('your_input_form_file_name');
$image = time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$image->move(public_path('images/'), $name);
```

Comment: getClientOriginalName takes thier extension with filename already